# How do you add tags to blocks so they can only be placed on 1 type of block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to make a Escapists map and i want to know how to add tags to blocks so they can only be placed on a certain block? Thank you to whoever anwsers my question.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0):

Use the can place on tag

```
/give @p minecraft:stone 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:stonebrick"]}
```